# Why does my command block keep reporting "Failed to execute 'execute' as {my username}"?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

The command works in chat but not in a repeating, always active command block. I even set the block to "requires redstone" and back to always active to try and fix it. The command in question is

```
/execute as @p[tag=Soda,hasitem={item=bow,location=slot.weapon.mainhand}] run execute if block ~ ~-1 ~ air run effect @e[r=10] slow_falling 1 1 true
```

The error message in the command block says:

> Failed to execute 'execute' as {my username}

Comment: Question closed. Nobody has answered and I have given up. I know it's not a case of people not seeing the question because multiple people have suggested edits and approved of those edits with mod power without a single person answering the question.

Comment: It's been 18 hours and the question has 16 views. People aren't always available all the time. Have a little faith.

Answer (score 1):

The check `if block ~ ~-1 ~ air` is done relative to who/what executes the root command. When executed from a command block with a block below it, the check will always fail.

To do the check relative to the selected player, add `at @s` after `as @p[tag=Soda,hasitem={item=bow,location=slot.weapon.mainhand}]`:

```
/execute as @p[tag=Soda,hasitem={item=bow,location=slot.weapon.mainhand}] at @s run execute if block ~ ~-1 ~ air run effect @e[r=10] slow_falling 1 1 true
```

Or, simplified to one `execute`:

```
/execute as @p[tag=Soda,hasitem={item=bow,location=slot.weapon.mainhand}] at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ air run effect @e[r=10] slow_falling 1 1 true
```